# History of microlocal analysis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ho.history-overview, pseudo-differential-operators, micro-local-analysis

Was the study of pseudo-differential operators the basis for the birth of microlocal analysis? I'm trying to find out how this branch of analysis was developed...

Comment: I believe microlocal analysis arose from two different directions. One is introduction of pseudodifferential operators to prove theorems about the regularity of solutions to elliptic PDEs. The other is the introduction of Fourier integral operators to study the propagation of singularities for the solution of a hyperbolic PDE. A seminal work on this is a paper by Peter Lax. I believe it is this one: Asymptotic solutions of oscillatory initial value problems.
Duke Math. J. 24 (1957), 627–646.

Comment: I think Calderon-Zygmund singular integrals led to pseudo-differential operators (Kohn and Nirenberg, I think)  while WKB asymptotic techniques (as interpreted by Keller, Lax, and Maslov) led to FIO's. Then Hormander wrapped the whole thing up.